# using mysqldump to import to RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am able to do a mysqldump locally that amounts to about 90kb using

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -p localDbName > /Users/Shared/localDbName-9-6-12.sql
```

I am trying to populate a newly setup amazon rds db. When I enter

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -p localDbName | mysql --host=Endpoint --user=MasterUsername --password=amazondbpassword amazonDBName
```

I get

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

then it prompts me for my own local password. After entering my password for the mysqldump i get

```
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

I would really appreciate some explanation/help for what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second error, `mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write` arises because of the first error, `-bash: mysql: command not found`. You sure mysql is installed properly on your machine, and the bin file is in your `$PATH`?

Comment: mysql was installed and working but I was missing `/usr/local/mysql/bin` from the $PATH. I didn't know what PATH was so I had to read about it. Anyway I added `/usr/local/mysql/bin` before the `mysql` in my command since that directory was missing from the $PATH. I've added editing the $PATH to my todo list but I'll have to learn how to do this on OSX first. Thanks again.

Comment: @cafman It's [pretty easy.](http://hathaway.cc/2008/06/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x/) Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the full path for mysqldump but forgot to use on mysql, you have to change the command to:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -p localDbName | /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql --host=Endpoint --user=MasterUsername --password=amazondbpassword amazonDBName
```

Good luck